# What are some ways to make a webapp only visible to me and the other developer?

Tags: security, networking, vpn, network-security

I'm developing a webapp with someone else, and I want a testing environment where I can push the site to so that he can use it too (and I don't want to just do everything locally).   I want to somehow make it so that only he and I can access it right now though, and I don't want to mess with the authentication of the webapp, because that's something we'll be working on and testing, so I don't want to pollute it with custom development logic.

I've considered a few things:

- Whitelisting our IP addresses on the site and writing a simple Middleware to forbid all requests not from our IPs (though the IP list would have to be dynamic since we may work on the app from different places, like coffeeshops, etc.)
- Setting up a VPN that we have to connect to before we can access the webapp (and whitelisting the VPN's IP).  It could be annoying having to connect to a VPN every time though.

I don't want to do anything with sessions or cookies because one of the things we'll be working on is login behavior and other parts of the app that would be accessed when the client has no cookies or sessions set.

Obviously in a corporate setting, this problem would be solved by everything just being on the same network, and it not being public, but that's not really an option for us since we won't always be physically in the same place.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest https://ngrok.com/ for simplicity without knowing your exact use case. This will work well if your friend just needs to access the site. If they need to make changes to the site, you will need something more complex.